# CSS Flexbox Centering Horizontally Issue

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flexbox container containing 2 `div` items. The flexbox container is setup for a row that centers the content inside. I am trying to figure out a way to center the contents of the row on the first item, and then have the second item be to the right of the first centered item.

Below is what I ended having to to do: have a the first item centered using the flexbox, but then I have to absolute position the second item to the desired position. Is there a way to remove the absolute positioning of the second item and have it appear just to the right of the first item, which is centered?

**HTML**

```
<div class="center-container">
    <div class="time">
        <span id="time">00:00</span>
    </div>
    <div class="time-ampm">
        <span id="time-ampm">XX</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.center-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: center;
}

.time {
    flex: 1;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #262626;
}

.time-ampm {
    position: absolute;
    top: 115px;
    left: 288px;
    /* flex: 1; <= this is what I want to use, not the absolute positioning used above */
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #858585;
}
```

This line shows where the flexbox centers the content if both of the items are set using flexbox (not the absolute positioning as above)

[image: current center]

This line shows where I want the flexbox to center the items (centered on the first item)

[image: desired center]

Comment: Just a reflexion. Do you want your items to grow (flex-grow > 0) ? In this case, the items will take the full space of the container, and there is no point in saying that the am text must be next to the otrher item ... Or am I missunderstanding something ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about setting the offset item width to 0?

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div>12:20</div>
  <div class="offset">AM</div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.container {
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items:baseline;
}
.offset {
  width:0;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dopQqo